# How i can to calculate the harmonic partial series: $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\left(H_k\right)^2-H^{(2)}_k}{k}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, harmonic-numbers

I have trying to calculate $$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\left(H_k\right)^2-H^{(2)}_k}{k} $$
I'm trying to apply Abel's Summation, i.e.: $$ \sum_{k=m}^n a_kb_k=A_nb_n-A_{m-1}b_m-\sum_{k=m}^{n-1}A_k\left(b_{k+1}-b_k\right)\tag{1}$$
where $\displaystyle A_k=\sum_{i=1}^k a_i$. Taking $m=1$, $\displaystyle a_k=\frac1k\to A_k=H_k$ and $\displaystyle b_k=\left(H_k\right)^2-H^{(2)}_k$ in $(1)$, i got that:

\begin{align*}
S_n&=H_n\left\{ \left(H_k\right)^2-H^{(2)}_k\right\}-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}H_k\left\{ \left(H_{k+1}\right)^2-H^{(2)}_{k+1}-\left(H_{k}\right)^2+H^{(2)}_{k}\right\} \\
&=H_n\left\{ \left(H_k\right)^2-H^{(2)}_k\right\}-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}H_k\left\{ \left(H_{k+1}+H_k\right)\left(H_{k+1}-H_k\right)-H^{(2)}_{k+1}+H^{(2)}_{k}\right\}\tag{2}\\
&=H_n\left\{ \left(H_k\right)^2-H^{(2)}_k\right\}-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}H_k\left\{ \left(2H_{k}+\frac1{k+1}\right)\left(\frac1{k+1}\right)-\frac1{(k+1)^2}\right\}\\
&=H_n\left\{ \left(H_k\right)^2-H^{(2)}_k\right\}-2\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{\left(H_k\right)^2}{k+1}\color{red}{-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{H_k}{(k+1)^2}}\color{red}{+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{H_k}{(k+1)^2}}\\
&=H_n\left\{ \left(H_k\right)^2-H^{(2)}_k\right\}-2\sum_{k=1}^{n }\frac{\left(H_{k-1}\right)^2}{k}
\end{align*}
Notice that, in $(2)$ i used the facts $\displaystyle H_{k+1}=H_k+\frac{1}{k+1}$ and $\displaystyle H_{k+1}^{(2)}=H_k^{(2)}+\frac{1}{(k+1)^2}$. My difficulty here is to evaluate the last sum above. Thank you in advance for any tip or solution and i accept any approach for the original problem.

Comment: Just a question : so do you want an answer to your last sum, or do you want an answer to the original problem, which could be different from your approach and your last sum, for example?

Comment: @TeresaLisbon I can perfectly consider both possibilities. But, out of curiosity, I would like to proceed with my approach.

Comment: Sure, thanks a lot. I was just asking , because recently I'd run into a situation where someone had asked a question but not told people that their emphasis was on their own approach, so someone else who had a different approach was a bit disappointed. I just wanted to make sure you emphasised your approach. Great! +1. (Note : I checked your question for duplicates on the site using Approach0 and didn't find anything. It is still possible that it may be a subpart of a larger computation that has been done on site).

Comment: @TeresaLisbon I apologize for the misunderstanding, I really confused my words. But I edited the final sentence of my post. Thank you for the signage!

Comment: You are welcome, and I hope you get a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

First, I wondered if the sign between the two harmonic numbers in the denominator is correct. Supposing this is the case, then we have

> $$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{H_k^2-H_k^{(2)}}{k}=\frac{1}{3}(H_n^3-3 H_nH_n^{(2)}-4 H_n^{(3)})+2\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{H_k}{k^2},\tag1$$

where for the last sum there is no known simpler form (e.g., to express it in terms of harmonic numbers).

During the calculations, I used that
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{H_k^2+H_k^{(2)}}{k}=\frac{1}{3}(H_n^3+3 H_nH_n^{(2)}+2 H_n^{(3)}),$$
which appears in **(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series** (for a proof, see pages $61$-$62$).

Also, by **Abel's summation** we immediately we have that
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{H_k}{k^2}+\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{H_k^{(2)}}{k}=H_n H_n^{(2)}+H_n^{(3)},$$
which is useful to get the result in $(1)$.